# How to get number form multi text files name and use it?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm a new python user. I try to write a script to deal with multiple text files all of them the same name and indexed like

```
sample1_freq780Hz_accRate600Hz_V3Volt_1_.txt
sample1_freq780Hz_accRate600Hz_V3Volt_2_.txt
sample1_freq780Hz_accRate600Hz_V3Volt_3_.txt
```

I used this code:

```
def get_numbers_from_filename(filename):
  result = re.search(r'\d+', filename).group(0)
  return result for filename in os.listdir('input/'): 
  print(get_numbers_from_filename(filename))
```

but it didn't give me the wanted results
I need a code to get the numbers as follow:

```
freq: 780 Hz
accRate: 600 Hz
V: 3 Volt
```

and how to deal and use these numbers as parameters inside the full script?

Comment: You need a code? Where is *your* code?

Comment: Please make an attempt to solve the problem before you ask a question. This is fairly easy to solve with regex or plain old string operations. Write some code and include it in your question.

Comment: I used this method but didn't give me the wanted result and I can't use it inside my script 


def get_numbers_from_filename(filename):
    result = re.search(r'\d+', filename).group(0)    
    return result
for filename in os.listdir('input/'):
   print(get_numbers_from_filename(filename))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
import re
import os
new_s = [dict(zip(['freq', 'accRate', 'V'], ['{} {}'.format(c, a) for a, c in zip(['Hz', 'Hz', 'Volt'], re.findall('(?<=freq)\d+|(?<=accRate)\d+|(?<=V)\d+', i))])) for i in os.listdir('input/')]
print(new_s[0])
```

Output:

```
{'freq': '780 Hz', 'accRate': '600 Hz', 'V': '3 Volt'}
```

To access the values in the list, iterate over `new_s`:

```
values = [new_s[0][i] for i in ['freq', 'accRate', 'V']]
```

Output:

```
['780 Hz', '600 Hz', '3 Volt']
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but if I have a lot of files, how to run the code for all of them? and how to use these numbers after extraction of them?

Comment: @etshooo You can iterate over the results of `os.listdir`. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. it's working very well. But I need to get only this result {'freq': '780 Hz', 'accRate': '600 Hz', 'V': '3 Volt'} not repeated on for each file because its the same. Also, how can I use this numbers in my calculations in the script? sorry for more questions because I'm a new python user

Comment: @etshooo Please see my recent edit.

Comment: It's working very well. Thanks in advance